# Round cube oauth authentication redirection 404 nginx error

Tags: email, roundcube

When roundcube gets redirected from oauth service nginx throws 404 not found. I have enabled oauth provider as generic and setup other required fields. Also nginx log says "/var/www/html/index.php/login/oauth" this file/folder not found.

I tries to edit nginx config but didnot work the problem persists..[404 Nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0WMu.png)